# Query to select businesses only

Tags: sql, select

I have a database of 200,000 accounts, which is a mix of individuals/households, i.e. John Doe and business names.  I would like to create a SELECT statement to select **ONLY the business names** and I believe the only possible way to write it would be:

```
and (account like'%inc.'
or account like'%ltd'
or account like'&gmbh')
```

...etc.

Has anyone ever written something like this?  I need to include international suffixes as well, but I cannot even find a reliable list of those by country.

Comment: What SQL dialect? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: What fields do you have in your table?

Comment: Don't you have a field indicating if the account is a person or a business?

Comment: @Carsten Would he be asking for this if he did?

Comment: I have a feeling he's using this query so he can add that field.

Comment: Your suggestion would only work for US companies. Legal forms of companies are different in every country.

Comment: @Skyp That's why he asked for international suffixes.

Comment: @Barmar I was just hoping that there's something that the asker is overlooking, because the alternative is virtually impossible.

Comment: I'm undecided whether this qualifies as unclear or off topic, but I'm voting to close. "Has anyone ever written something like this?" is hardly a constructive question, and "what company suffixes exist worldwide?" is not really possible to answer (even if someone does know, the list is almost certainly unmanageably large). One solution to the programming problem is already included in the question by the OP. The question might be possible to make on topic and answerable, but I'm not sure I can readily see how given what is written currently.

Comment: What you could try doing is creating a list of all the unique suffixes in the database. Then go through them, figuring out which are company suffixes and which are people's surnames.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, you can't do it.  If your data is so dirty that you don't know the difference between a person and a business, why do you think there would be an `'inc.'`, '`gmbh'`, or `'ltd'` on the end?

Then, you need to consider exciting company names such as "John Deere" or "Arthur Andersen".  These look a lot like a person's name.  And if you don't have a company structure indicator, then how will you be able to tell the difference?

The right solution is to use a third-party vendor to correct the names of the accounts. You can also consider changing your operational systems (whoever inputs the name) to put in a person/company indicator.  By the way, what do you do with individuals that are incorporated themselves, say as an S-Corp in the US?

If you want to start an ad hoc effort, then I would start by looking at the last word in each name:

```
select right(name, charindex(' ', reverse(name))), count(*), min(name), max(name)
from t
where name like '% %'
group by left(name, charindex(' ', name))
```

(This is SQL Server syntax to get the last word in the name.)  Look through these to see the list of possible suffixes.

By the way, if this is international, I wouldn't be surprised if some languages use a prefix to indicate a company rather than a suffix.